# X Window Server that acts as a pass-through

Tags: x11, xorg, x-server

Is there a settings for Xorg (or any X window server) that creates a "stub" of an X server such that it accepts API calls from applications and then completely disregards them rather than processing the calls, updating the frame buffer, and writing out to memory? I need to be able to run a graphical application (such as Firefox) but I don't actually care about the graphical output and would like to reduce the rendering overhead as much as possible. I'm trying to get web page timings that are unaltered by graphical rendering.

Alternately, is there some way to "record" all of the X server API calls, dump them to disk, and then replay them later such that I could decouple the web timings from the graphical rendering but still create screenshots of what the application looked at at various points in time?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `Xvfb`.  From the manual:

> ```
>    Xvfb  is  an X server that can run on machines with no display hardware
>    and no physical input devices.  It emulates a  dumb  framebuffer  using
>    virtual memory.
> ```

Comment: I'm currently using `xvfb` but it still writes to memory. I don't want the X server to do *anything*, just make it appear to the application that there is an X server listening

Comment: @Suever There is no other way.  X is event-based, the X server needs to return meaningful answers when queried by clients for sizes, positions, etc.  A completely "void" X server doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a program to do this in 1996 and only recently removed from debian, called `xmon`, which was in two parts, `xmond` which filtered the requests and replies to an X11 server, and `xmonui` which was a gui in which you could toggle which requests were to be suppressed  and so not draw anything.  It was an offshoot of the `xscope` program (to trace the requests and replies) which is still distributed. However, to find the [sources](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/x11/xmon/README.html) and compile `xmon` today you need to be a bit of an enthusiast. I suppose it was removed as there were no more X11 bugs to be debugged...

[man xmon](https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=xmon): *The following diagram shows the relationships between xmon and the xmon
  daemon.  and the clients and the server.*

```
                             ----------
                             | xmonui |
                             ----------
                                 |
                                 v
        ------------         ----------
        | client 1 |<------->|        |
        ------------         |        |       ----------
             :               | xmond  |<----->| server |
             :               |        |       ----------
        ------------         |        |
        | client n |<------->|        |
        ------------         ----------
                                 |
                                 v
                       monitor output to stdout
```

An alternative optimisation you might try with `Xvfb` is to create a very small screen of say 64x64 pixels and perhaps of depth 1 (monochrome), and place the firefox window off-screen, so not much will be rendered as it will not be visible.